# How to implement the Save AS dialog box in javascript with Save As type as .bmp files(Bitmap Files)

Tags: javascript

Could some one guide me with the code of creating Save As dialog box in java script that should work in IE and the Save As type should be .bmp files.
I have one running code but that is working only for text .Here is the code that I am using.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function save(){
str = document.forms[0].t1.value;
mydoc = document.open();
mydoc.write(str);
mydoc.execCommand("saveAs",true,".text");
mydoc.close();
return false;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body class="body">
<form id="form1" action="" onsubmit="">
<input type="text" name="t1"/>
<input type="button" value="SaveAs" onclick="save()"/>
</form>
</html>
```

But this is working only for text I want for .bmp files.
Could someone help me in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried `mydoc.execCommand("saveAs",true,".bmp");`

Comment: Yes I have tried but its not working

Comment: I think you can't do that... Because, in order to download (not show), you need to tell to browser with specific headers from server side. See more [http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-4915](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-4915)

Comment: When I put .bmp after clicking on Save As button the dialog box is only not coming.Is there is some another code for Save As dialog Box in javascript with Save as type as .bmp file.Please Help me with the code